# apache beam with python pardo with multi pCollections input

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm new in apache_beam and I'm trying to develop a pipeline.
I have 2 pCollections with same format and I have another pCollection with other format.
I try to do a ParDo function that for each item in pCollection 3 depending a value o this item search if item exist in pCollection 1 or 2 to complete output with info of pCollection 1 or 2.
But I dont know how do it this ParDo function.

This is my code:

```
output = (
      pCollection1, pCollection2, pCollection3
      | 'ParDo function' >> beam.ParDo(SearchData()))
```

And this is my ParDo fucntion:

```
class SampleScores(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
      
      # here I don't know how call a collection because I have only a "element"

      return xxx
```

thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Side inputs? https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to have `process(self, element, pcoll1, pcoll2)`, side inputs might help you with that.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I deleted my answer. Will have a look tomorrow, but it looks that you do need side inputs

Comment: @MilanCermak. Thanks by your comment. This is what I needed. Side inputs!.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

> Have you looked at Side inputs? beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side- inputs If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to have process(self, element, pcoll1, pcoll2), side inputs might help you with that. – Milan Cermak yesterday

Thanks @MilanCermak